# Kinetic js 5.1 globalCompositeOperation how to

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, composite, globalcompositeoperation

I'm fairly new to Kinetic JS.
Im trying to get some .globalCompositeOperation to work in 2 parts of a project I have, I have tried several solutions I can find here, using 'drawFunc', and 'sceneFunc', etc... but so far no luck.

One part of the project Im trying to get 'destination-out' to work on a kinetic.Sprite:

```
var strokesSprite = new Kinetic.Sprite({
                        image: e,
                        animation: 'intro',
                        animations: {
                            'intro': config.spritestrokes.frames
                        },
                        frameRate: 7,
                        frameIndex: 0,
                        sceneFunc: function (ctx) {
                            ctx.save();
                            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                            ctx.restore();
                        }

    var strokes = new Kinetic.Layer({
                        width: 1280,
                        height: 1280,
                        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
                        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
                        offset: {
                            x: 1280 / 2,
                            y: 1280 / 2
                        }
                    });
                    strokes.add(backgroundPainted);
                    strokes.add(strokesSprite);
                    strokes.draw();
                    stage.add(strokes);
```

"backgroundPainted" is a Kinetic.Image

Unfortunately all I get here is the sprite layer being animated on top of the 'backgroundPainted', but no composite operation being applied :(.

For the 2nd instance I have, its actually very similar, I just have 2 layers, both with shapes inside, added to the stage. Im applying the same 'sceneFunc' to the layer on top, and drawing them then.
The layers just both display, with no composition being applied. :(

Any pointers on what I should look at? I see that for example 'drawFunc' has been changed to 'sceneFunc' recently, and maybe something else has changed, as Ive tried pretty much all examples I can find here on stack.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**KineticJS does not support `globalCompositeOperation`.**

KineticJS gives you a wrapper around an html5 canvas context, but that wrapper is a subset of the context which does not include the context.globalCompositeOperation property.

**A workaround**

You can create a canvas element (without appending it to the page).  Do your compositing on that offscreen canvas. To present that canvas inside KineticJS, just create a Kinetic.Image with the image property pointing to the offscreen canvas:

```
var myOffscreenCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");

... do compositing ...

// this Kinetic.Image will display myOffscreenCanvas

var myCompositedImage = new Kinetic.Image({

    image:myOffscreenCanvas,

    ...

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, an issue for me on performance, is that my objects are in Kinectic form, so id have to create a offscreen canvas, draw my kinectic objects (drawImage) using "layerAB.getCanvas()._canvas", then do the globalComposite, and then redraw the final result back to my layer?

And is it possible to draw to a Layer which hasn't been added to the stage? I've tried, and then draw that layer's canvas elsewhere, but nothing is being drawn if my "offscreen" canvas is not added to the stage.

Comment: You can convert your Kinetic Nodes to images using `myNode.toImage` and then `drawImage` to draw that image on the canvas. (ditto with a whole layer or the entire stage). There is no material performance hit when drawing from an offscreen canvas to a Kinetic.Image.  Reason being that the canvas maintains a pixel array which is just blitted (bulk copied) onto any pixel based image (like Kinetic.Image).  As to how to get canvas into Kinetic.Shape: you can just drawImage(offscreenCanvas,x,y).  The canvas can be used instead of an imageObj.

Comment: Thank you markE, Im looking into this now, I reckon it was the missing link :).

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when trying this...
`
var tWidth = brush.getWidth();
var tHeight = brush.getHeight();
brush.toImage({
width: tWidth,
height: tHeight,
x: 0,
y: 0,
callback: function (e) {
...
}
`
...its throwing:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_applyTransform' of null kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js:1419Kinetic.Util.addMethods.drawScene kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js:1419Kinetic.Util.addMethods.toDataURL kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js:685Kinetic.Util.addMethods.toImage

Comment: Ok, this was happening because I wasn't adding the shape to a layer on the stage first. Unfortunately the performance is quite low, I guess due waiting for the callback, this is basically like a clone brush between 2 layers, as you move with your pointer, the layer on top "gets deleted", and you see the one underneath. From using raw canvas I concluded that using "destination-out" was the best performing option, but keen on other options too.